# ACPI Errors/Exeptions, why they spam, how to know and fix it?

Tags: linux-kernel, logs, acpi

I've been having these errors pollute my dmesg:

```
[21720.400079] ACPI Error: [\_TZ_.THRM] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20130328/psargs-359)
[21720.400093] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L1C] (Node f584ec80), AE_NOT_FOUND (20130328/psparse-537)
[21720.400112] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L1C] (20130328/evgpe-580)
[21960.800116] ACPI Error: [\_TZ_.THRM] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20130328/psargs-359)
[21960.800130] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L1C] (Node f584ec80), AE_NOT_FOUND (20130328/psparse-537)
[21960.800149] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L1C] (20130328/evgpe-580)
```

This happens infinitely. I tried each keyword and haven't found anything remotely relevant. This happens in each distribution I try. How do I diagnostic the origins of the message?

Appart from polluting the message ring, I haven't found any other problem related to this.

Comment: I have the same issue. In my case, I guess it is due my wireless card. I have a `rtl8188ee` driver according to `lspci -k`, what about you?

Comment: @auraham nothing of the like, my system is a desktop. No wireless. An HP Pavilion a1104x if you are curious.

Comment: I have this same issue. In my case, it has actually negatively affected my system, because it has bloated my /var/log folder to a point where my root partition is completely filled.

Comment: Bug reported to the kernel devs here: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=188331

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These warnings are triggered because of firmware errors. Try a newer BIOS version which hopefully fixes these errors. If you do not have access to newer BIOS, you can try overriding your DSDT/SSDT with tables that got the faulty code replaced/removed.

It does not seem to be harmful, perhaps it is some thermal health/throttle check that is invoked every 240 seconds (4 minutes).

As for the technical details, these messages originates from the ACPI core. The `\_GPE._Lxx` methods are level-triggered interrupts if I remember correctly and are triggered by the hardware (not Linux). Apparently this specific methods tries to evaluate some method or object at `\_TZ.THRM` which failed because this ACPI scope does not exist.

Comment: The BIOS is updated with the latest version from the OEM... and "overriding" seems dangerous, should I use [this guide](https://01.org/linux-acpi/documentation/overriding-dsdt)? Also, if I change the DSDT/SSDT should just nuke the problem or there some method to make it do what it's supposed to do? Also, seems that I should rebuild my kernel...

Comment: @Braiam That page looks fine overall, but I suggest not to override the whole DSDT/SSDT unless absolutely necessary (in your case is just an annoying warning). Besides overwriting the full DSDT/SSDT, you can also use the `custom_method` kernel module to overwrite a single ACPI method. You can use this to create a dummy `\_TZ.THRM` node (with the expected children) or overwrite `\_GPE._L1C` to remove the call. However, do not simply edit things away without understanding what is happening. It might have negative side-effects (like disabling power or thermal throttling to take an extra example).